# Linear Time-Invariant system without State-space form

Tags: convolution, linear-systems, state-space

I would like to know whether there is any LTI system that does not have state-space representation, but do have a convolution representation. and vice-versa. Can you name some examples for me to research further on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a homework problem, but I'll bite.

The thing with a state-space representation is that it needs to have finite dimension:

$$
x_{k+1} = \mathbf{A} x_k + \mathbf{B} u_k\\
y_k = \mathbf{C} x_k + \mathbf{D} u_k
$$

where $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and the other matrices and vectors have appropriate dimensions.

Here, the dimension, $n$, must be finite.

So an LTI system that can be represented as a transcendental impulse response cannot be written that way.

For example:
$$
y_k = {\rm sinc}(0.1 k) \star x_k
$$
will not be representable in a state-space formulation.